# SAP UI5 binding by reference to another value

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

I have a large model with many levels and attributes and I want to have one Input in my XML view which will always edit 1 attribute from the model, but every time it will be a different attribute.

I want to edit for example attributes on following paths:

```
myModel>/user/0/surname
myModel>/user/1/name
myModel>/user/2/nickname
myModel>/user/3/email
```

Let's say that now I am interested in editing the nickname of user nr2 so I will save its path to a variable:

```
myModel.setProperty("currentlyEditedPath", "myModel>/user/2/nickname");
```

And I want to define my Input like this:

```
<Input value="{myModel>/currentlyEditedPath}" >
```

And what happens is that UI5 will allow me to edit the string "myModel>/user/2/nickname" it self. But its wrong. I only want to use the string as a reference to some other value deep in the model which should be modified and updated. I should probably write something like this, but I cannot find the correct way:

```
<Input value="{ ${myModel> ${myModel>/currentlyEditedPath} } } " >
```

Any ideas, please? .. as simple as possible. Best inline.

Comment: Maybe I could also use Element binding... https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.34.9/docs/guide/91f05e8b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the Element binding is the good way. Feel free to comment on this:

```
var oInput = sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId("myFragmentID","myInputID");
oInput.bindElement("myModel>/user/2");
oInput.bindProperty("value", "myModel>nickname");
```

Or I can also place the value to the XML:

```
<Input value="{myModel>nickname}" >
```